# ¿Cómo guardar la variable sin cambiar de scope?

Tags: javascript, recursión

¿Es imposible guardar el valor de las variables sin colocarlas afuera? Para que en lugar de hacer la función de forma iterativa, hacerla de forma recursiva.

Si realmente no existe ninguna forma, ¿por qué?

Guardar el valor de las variables que están dentro de la función para así hacer la función de manera recursiva, sin usar bucles.

**El fin de la función es mostrar la tabla de un número, de esta manera el primer parámetro *es el numero del cual se desea saber la tabla*, y *el segundo el tamaño de la tabla*, o sea, si los parametros son `(4,10)` seria la tabla del 4 hasta 10, o sea, `(4*1 ... 4*10)`**

```js
function ab(n,max){ 
 var maximo=parseInt(max,10) || 0, // el maximo
     contador = 1, // un contador
     numeroParaMultiplicar = parseInt(n,10) || 0, // el numero para la tabla
     numerosMultiplicados = []; // aqui se añadirá la tabla
if(contador <= maximo) { // mientras el contador sea igual o menor que el maximo especifcado se realizara el bucle
    //numerosMultiplicados.push(numeroParaMultiplicar*contador);
    numerosMultiplicados.push(numeroParaMultiplicar*contador); //multiplico
    contador++; // se suma 1 al contador
    ab(numeroParaMultiplicar,maximo); //vuelvo a llamar a la funcion
 }
 return numerosMultiplicados;
}

console.log(ab(4,10));
```

Comment: Puedes explicar el problema? No esta claro lo que preguntas.

Comment: Editado Einer _!!

Comment: Eduardo, intenta explicar que hace la funcion y asi quizas pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Listo Einer, ya está editado el post y la función con comentarios

Comment: Aver, ¿la idea es mostrar la tabla de multiplicacion de un numero especificandole el limite de la tabla en el segundo parametro?

Comment: [Es esto lo que quieres?](http://jsbin.com/pesogucaga/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario tener un bucle para realizar todas las multiplicaciones, puedes simplemente invocar a la función con el número para multiplicar siguiente/anterior hasta llegar a un caso base.

Los resultados puedes acumularlos en un array, pasándolo como parámetro de la función, inicializandolo en su invocación como array vacío. O simplemente imprimirlos.

Esta función recursiva tiene:

- Caso base: `n*0 = 0`
- Caso recursivo: invoca a la función con `max-1`, es decir `n*max`, `n*(max-1)`, `n*(max-2)`...`n*(max-max)` = `n*0`. Por ejemplo partiendo de 4*10 y continuando las llamadas recursivas con 4*9, 4*8....4*1, 4*0

```js
function multTable(n,max,results){
   if(max === 0){
     results.push(0);
     return results;
   }else{
      results.push(n*max);
      return multTable(n,max-1,results);
   }
}

console.log(multTable(4,10,[]));
console.log(multTable(3,10,[]));
console.log(multTable(10,10,[]));
console.log(multTable(4,5,[]));
console.log(multTable(4,0,[]));
```

Además, ten cuidado como has definido la recursión en tu implementación actual, ya que resulta en un bucle infinito. cada nueva invocación a `ab` asigna el valor 1 a `contador`, y `maximo` es siempre 10, por lo que la condición de corte `contador>máximo` nunca evaluará a `true`

Comment: Una sola pregunta, porqué al volver a llamar a la función lo haces con return?

Comment: Porque de lo contrario la funcion devolveria void/undefined en la llamada recursiva, es necesario retornar un valor para que sea procesado por la llamada anterior

Comment: En este caso tu función podría no retornar nada para el caso recursivo, pero para poder ver los resultados deberías imprimir fuera de la función el valor del array que le pasas por parámetro (el cual acumula los valores). Es decir, depende de si quieres que tu función retorne o no un valor.

Comment: gracias marcos! !!